# Querying the Data with Min and Max of 2 attributes

Tags: sql-server, group-by

I have a SQL Server Datatable with a table: `Problems`

Here is the structure

```
     Name   Problem     Date          IsCurrent
     -----------------------------------------
     John   Fever       22-06-2015        1
     Davis  High BP     20-06-2015        0
     John   Headache    25-05-2105        0
     John   Fever       20-05-2015        1
     Davis  High BP     10-05-2015        1
```

I want to query this table for 1 Name at a time. For e.g. if i query for `Problem` with `John`.

My result set should be

```
1. Fever    20-05-2015 (Min Date of the Problem)   1 (IsCurrent status as of the latest date)
2. Headache 25-05-2015                             0
```

for `Davis` the result set will be

```
1. High BP   10-05-2015 (Min Date of the Problem) 0 (IsCurrent status as of the latest date)
```

Since both `Min Date` and `Max Date` are required here, what will be my most optimized query?

Comment: Make group by on `Name` and `Problem` column in query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select Name, problem, MIN([date]) mindate,max(date) maxdate into #t1
 from ProblemTable  
group by Name, problem

select Name, problem,max(date) maxdate, iscurrent into #t2
 from ProblemTable group by Name, problem, iscurrent

select t1.Name,t1.Problem, t1.mindate, t2.IsCurrent from #t1 t1
inner join
t2 t2 on t1.Name=t2.Name and t1.Problem=t2.Problem and t1.maxdate=t2.maxdate
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `IsCurrent` is always up to date and only `1` for one problem per name at a time, the following should work:

```
SELECT
    t.Problem
    ,t.MIN([Date])
    ,MAX(t.IsCurrent)
FROM ProblemTable t
WHERE t.Name = 'John'
GROUP BY Name, Problem
```

Grouping by `Name` and `Problem` will leave you with `[Date]` and `IsCurrent` requiring aggregation. You want the minimum date, and whether the grouped problem IsCurrent. Selecting the maximum `IsCurrent` value will find that out for you, as the value `1` will only appear for the Problem which is set to current.